# Access and close the database automatically in ASP.net C# web form web application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sqlconnection

I am developing a web application using MySql database. This is a web form application using .NET Framework 4.5.

Lately I have been developing many functions that are accessing the database in high frequency.

Instead of creating and closing the database connection every time I would like to optimize the opening and closing of the database connections, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should research the using keyword. It is a short-hand widely used in the C# programming language.

The following two blocks are synonymous:

```
var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
     con.Open();
} 
finally
{
     con.Dispose();
}
```

---

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
      con.Open();
}
```

Comment: Teeny, tiny nitpick, It's probably a `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` being used.

Answer (score 0):

If these functions are all in the same class, you can create a connection Property (get and set method) to optimize